# how to change states more efficiently?

Tags: reactjs

I have elements that are editable and the code I have right now is pretty long and probably just unnecessary, so how can I make this just shorter and cleaner?

````
    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.target.id)

        if (e.target.id === "name") {
            this.setState({
                name: e.target.value
            })
        } else if (e.target.id === "address") {
            this.setState({
                address: e.target.value
            })
        } else if (e.target.id === "phone") {
            this.setState({
                phone: e.target.value
            })
        } else if (e.target.id === "email") {
            this.setState({
                email: e.target.value
            })
        } 
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

If your `target.id` matching the state key (as it seems from your example), you can use [Property accessors](https://Property%20accessors):

```
const targetId = e.target.id;

if (this.state[targetId]) { // check if id exists
  this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });

} else { // default case
  // fill
}
```